# can i install ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64 to HP Integrity rx2620 Server

Tags: server

i don't know too much about computer scince(especially in linux eara).my major is biology, recently i need to analysis some next generation sequencing data of one insect, so i may better use linux. in our lab there is a server(HP Integrity rx2620 Server) , and no body using it for several years, it has a password no body knows. so i wanna install OS to the machine. here, i want to know can i install ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64 to HP Integrity rx2620 Server? if it could, could it be done by USB stick or just from CD-room?

thanks for the tips in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your server should work just fine with Ubuntu Server. If there are any hardware problems at all (which are very unlikely), I'm sure you can google a work-around. You can burn the .iso to a CD (my recommendation) or use a utility like [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to put it on a flash drive or external hard drive. If you haven't used a GNU/Linux operating system (what you call Linux) before, you might want to get something with a lightweight GUI like [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) or, if you're low on RAM or want something more lightweight, [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/). Lubuntu has more bugs than Xubuntu (from my experience), so even if you don't need the bells and whistles of Xfce (Xubuntu), I recommend it anyway. Just because it's a server machine doesn't mean you need Ubuntu Server. Even if you are using it as a server, get something with a GUI so you can configure it easily. I have been using Ubuntu for years and I still have no idea how to configure networking from a CLI (command line interface).

Comment: I looked it up and HP says that they have official support for Red Hat 4, which is very old. However, drivers are typically made into the kernel, meaning Ubuntu should work fine, server and desktop (Xubuntu, Lubuntu) versions. Also, it may be a server, but remember that all that means is that it was built with performance and networking in mind and should make an excellent Xubuntu machine- regardless if you're using it for server or desktop purposes.

Comment: thank you @Fuzzy. i am downloading Xubuntu from link. before download i noticed that Xubuntu just have one version(desktop), it dose not have server version like ubuntu has, right? another question,this morning i burned the ubuntu.iso to u disk deiver and insert it to the machine, and HP Integrity rx2620 bios does not have USB slection in its boot priority menu, but it does have "internal bootable DVD" at the boot menu. does that mean i should burn the iso. file to the CD,and then i can install it?